# fopen(w+): failed to open stream

Tags: php, html, wkhtmltopdf

I'm currently creating a quote which has values that can be changed. It requires PDF conversion.

This conversion is done using wkhtmltopdf, unfortunately the old way I used did not convert the changed values and that is why my script is changed.

However it fails at line 7:

```
$fp = fopen('w+','/tmp/tmp.html');
```

The complete script:

```
<?php
try {
   $content = $_REQUEST['content'];
    if(!file_exists('/tmp') ){
       mkdir('/tmp', 0777);
    }
   $fp = fopen('w+','/tmp/tmp.html');
   if($fp){
     fwrite($fp, $content);
     fclose($fp);

     $filename = '/tmp/out_' . time() .'.pdf'; // output filename
     shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf /tmp/tmp.html ' . $filename);

     //then eventually ask user for download the result
     header("Content-type:application/pdf");

     // It will be called output.pdf
     header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='output.pdf'");

    readfile($filename);
  }else{
     echo 'html file could not be created';
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
//
```

I hope anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.
If more info is necessary, let me know.

Comment: The arguments are supposed to be the other way around [`fopen(string $filename , string $mode)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you.. That was indeed the case.